# How can I supply data to a JavaFX 2.0 LineChart from a file?

Tags: javafx-2

I need to create a LineChart and want to supply the data points via a file. I.e. the numerical values are in a text file. Is this native functionality or do I have to do it the old fashioned way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such native functionality (I think because it's hard to guess desired format -- csv, xml, json, etc). So you just need to implement simple file reader which will add `Chart.Data` for each read line.